# Filter results in has many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm struggling to filter some results.. I have a table called "Process", and another called "Actors". Process has many Actors. Here's the model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Process extends Model
{
    public function actors()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Actor::class)->orderBy('actor');
    }
}
```

So I have a view where I show all process and their actors. The thing is, I want to make an option to filter, where I would check if the *Auth::user()->username* is the same as Actor->actor.

I tried something along the lines of:

```
public function index()
    {
        $processes = Process::all();

        $processes ->actors()->where('actor', 'Test')->get();

        return view('process.process', compact('processes '));

    }
```

(In the Where I compare to Test for testing purposes, if I did get it to work I would change it to *Auth::user()->username* obviously)

This shows the following error:

> BadMethodCallException Method
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::actors does not exist.

I've tried some variations(running a foreach in the controller for example, but either I did it wrong or thats not the way to do it...) but to no avail. Any help is greatly apreciated!

Comment: Are you able to get the collection of actors for `$processes->actors` with out any where and other?

Comment: Yes, In my view I have a foreach like this: "@foreach ($processes->actors as $actor)" and it works just fine.

Comment: Then can you try `$processes->actors->where('actor', 'Test')` and let me know what you are getting?

Comment: I did, and it works. Problem is, doing it like this ALL processes still show, only inside each one of them I have only showing the Actors called 'test'. What I was looking for is to only show the processes which have an actor called 'test' in them.

Comment: what you are getting for `$processes->actors()->get()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to grab all processes of the current authenticated user if yes this is what you need.

```
public function index()
{
    $processes = Process::whereHas('actors',function($query){
                     $query->where('id',Auth::user()->id);
                  });

    return view('process.process', compact('processes '));

}
```

Comment: How you are specifying this is current $process or the particular instance ?

Comment: What he need is all process of the particular authenticated user right? @PrafullaKumarSahu

Comment: But he is retrieving the actors using `$process`  and that process is specific I think what you have not specified.

Comment: The current process that he is using is increasing number of queries so we can't use that for performance purposes @PrafullaKumarSahu

Comment: Cheers @JohnyJohnson